# Check if email exist with emailjs in node js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use the emailjs (https://github.com/eleith/emailjs) for sending emails in nodejs.

I want to check if email exists before sending it and I do not want to send an email to know this.

So, My question is: How to check if an email address exists on the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

At the network level, receiving and sending email are different operations. In a typical email client (like outlook or a wwebmail program) they appear integrated, but that is an elaborate illusion.

Your question mentioned a npm module to use SMTP to send emails. That's the way email clients do it.

Email clients use the POP3 protocol and sometimes the IMAP protocol to read messages from mailboxes on email servers. Some npm modules handling pop3 are available for node.js, and you can use one. But you will have to create the code to "know this email exists" as you put it in your question. You will read emails from the mailbox -- all of them! -- and examine them for the information you need to "know this email exists."  If the inbox you read also belongs to a person, you need to be careful to tell POP3 to leave the messages on the server.